# Plot two Graphs on Same Chart R, ggplot2 par(mfrow())

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am getting the feeling after doing some digging that this probably will not work and I will need to discover an alternate method but I am going to ask anyways.

I have to graphs that I want to plot on the same chart, by making use of `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

My code for the graphs is as follows:

```
mTotal <- mean(data$Total)
mTotal

data$valence1[data$Total >= mTotal] <- "Above Mean"
data$valence1[data$Total < mTotal] <- "Below Mean"
data$valence2[data$Delta >= 0] <- "Positive"
data$valence2[data$Delta < 0] <- "Negative"

data

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

ggplot(data,
       aes(x = Index,
           y = Total,
           fill = valence1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           colour = "black",
           alpha = 0.618) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mTotal,
             linetype = "dashed",
             colour = "red") + 
  annotate("text", x = 19, y = mTotal + 50,
           label = "Problem Period") + 
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Ambulance Arrivals") +
  ggtitle("Ambulance Arrivals by Month
          Jan 2013 - Feb 2014")

maxDelta <- max(data$Delta)
maxDelta
minDelta <- min(data$Delta)
minDelta

ggplot(data,
       aes(x = Index,
           y = Delta,
           fill = valence2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "identity",
           colour = "black",
           alpha = 0.618) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 13.5, xmax = 24.5,
           ymin = minDelta, ymax = maxDelta,
           alpha = 0.3, fill = "blue") +
  annotate("text", x = 19, y = maxDelta + 25,
           label = "Problem Period") +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Change in Arrivals") + 
  ggtitle("Change in Ambulance Arrivals Month over Month")
```

If this is not possible, then a direction to a better route would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look at the `gridExtra` package and use `grid.arrange` instead. Works wonderfully with `ggplot`.

Just assign your first `ggplot` call to a variable (e.g. `plot1`) and the next to another (e.g. `plot2`) and do something like:

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a rather simple solution and did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What if I wanted to choose for `plot1` and `plot2` to be stacked and then say `plot3` and `plot4`  to stack next to it. Similar to `par(mfcol)`

Comment: @Bonono Just set `nrow` and `ncol` to sensible values, and experiment to figure out whether the plots "fill" the layout left-to-right or top-to-bottom.

Comment: Can I ask for a slight deviation on this question. this example is plotting plots that have been already created. I am after a solution where I create a ggplot() figure within a loop so don't have 6 objects to plot up at the end. I guess what I am trying to ask is can I set up a grid.arrange() and then add the figures within a loop? like I commonly do with par() in basic graphics R

Comment: @Cyrillm_44 it's prbly better as a separate question, but don't use a loop, use `lapply` or `purrr::map` and follow something like this — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570514/grid-arrange-using-list-of-plots

Answer (score 6):

`mfrow` is for use with base graphics.  For `ggplot2` you need a different approach, like the one mentioned by @hrbmstr, or this one:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")

a <- qplot(x = rnorm(10))
b <- qplot(x = rnorm(10))

vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))

print(a, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(b, vp = vplayout(1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me an alternate method to hrbrmstrs' solution

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I just had to deal with this and found a simple solution for multiplots simply by looking in the in the `gridExtra` package (builind on @hrbrmstr):

```
library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")
pl <- lapply(1:4, function(.x) qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main=paste("plot", .x)))
marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

[image: Multi-plot with ggplot and grid]

Just put you plot generating function in the `lapply`and you're all set.

Comment: What if I wanted to choose for `plot1` and `plot2` to be stacked and then say `plot3` and `plot4`  to stack next to it. Similar to `par(mfcol)`

Comment: @Bonono I assume this is what you will want `library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")
pl <- lapply(1:4, function(.x) qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main=paste("plot", .x)))
lay <- rbind(c(1,3,4),
             c(2,3,4))
grid.arrange(grobs=pl,layout_matrix=lay)` which will give you [this](http://i.imgur.com/7izwkMz.png). For further reference also see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)

Comment: Thank you victor! Here's something even easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877386/grid-arrange-ggplot2-plots-by-columns-instead-of-by-row-using-lists/40877889?noredirect=1#comment68971679_40877889

Comment: Cool @Bonono! Thanks