# grid.arrange ggplot2 plots by columns instead of by row using lists

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

I want create a multiplot of `ggplot2` plots from a list using `grid.arrange` but arrange them by columns before doing it by rows.

```
gg_list1 <- list(qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars), 
                 qplot(hp, wt, data = mtcars), 
                 qplot(qsec, wt, data = mtcars))

gg_list2 <- list(qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars), 
                 qplot(hp, wt, data = mtcars), 
                 qplot(qsec, wt, data = mtcars))
```

I know I can do this:

```
do.call(grid.arrange,c(gg_list1,gg_list2 , ncol = 2, nrow  = 3))
```

but it fills from left to right before top to bottom.

I've tried this:

```
 do.call(grid.arrange, c(gg_list1, arrangeGrob(gg_list2, nrow = 3), ncol = 2))
```

But get `Error: length(widths) == ncol is not TRUE`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `grobs` parameter to pass a list and the `as.table` parameter to fill column-wise, so flattened with `c`, all you need is

```
grid.arrange(grobs = c(gg_list1, gg_list2), ncol = 2, as.table = FALSE)
```

[image: grid plot]

If you want a more complex layout, use the `layout_matrix` parameter:

```
my_layout <- rbind(c(1, 1:3, 4), c(1, 1:3, 4), c(1, 1:3, 5), c(1, 1:3, 6))

my_layout
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    1    2    3    4
## [2,]    1    1    2    3    4
## [3,]    1    1    2    3    5
## [4,]    1    1    2    3    6

grid.arrange(grobs = c(gg_list1, gg_list2), layout_matrix = my_layout)
```

[image: complex grid plot]

See [the `arrangeGrob` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks Alistaire. Your first example using the `grob =` argument still fills from left to right before top to bottom, fyi, but maybe you knew that? Your 2nd example WORKED! Thank you so much - I've been trying to figure this out for the past 4h, no joke.

Comment: Oops. You can add `as.table = FALSE` to fill column-wise; I'll edit.